# Find the shortest string that is not a sub-string of a set of strings

Tags: algorithms

Alphabet: `abc`

Sample input:

1. `abc`
2. `cba`
3. `aabbcc`
4. `aaabbbccc`
5. `caac`

Sample good outputs: `acb`, `cab`, `cac` and others, since they are not substrings of any other, and because all strings of length 1 and 2 are present.

Sample bad outputs:

- `aab` since it is a substring of 3)
- `aaaa` because it is not minimal: we have other solutions with 3 characters only

Questions:

- What are the best ways to solve it?
- Does the problem have a well known coined name?
- What is the complexity of the calculation in terms of the input size (number of strings N and maximum string length M)?
- What is the average asymptotic size of the output considering random uniformly distributed inputs?

Related questions:

- [Algorithm Request: "Shortest non-existing substring over given alphabet"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/algorithm-request-shortest-non-existing-substring-over-given-alphabet) seems to be the case for a single input string. If we can find a trivial reduction we can close as a duplicate.

Applications:

- for file uploads, browsers use the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` encoding. This encoding can send several files in a single HTTP request. Files are sent directly without character encoding, so to separate the files, the browser has to find a string that is not contained in any of the files. I'd like to know how that can be done optimally. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean/28380690#28380690
- apparently this has some interest for bioinformatics, although I know nothing about that domain: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/shortest-strings-not-present-in-the-human-genome . There has been some discussion on that question, but the answers there are more heuristic than algorithmic.

Comment: You will find a very helpful similarity in a question that has already been answered: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/algorithm-request-shortest-non-existing-substring-over-given-alphabet

Comment: @FrancescoGramano thanks! That is indeed the case for one sequence.

Comment: Note that the other question deals with *substrings*, a different problem.

Comment: @Raphael I don't quite understand, is it because there is a difference between substrings and subsequences? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. The main issue with the approaches given [there](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896) is that a string of length $n$ has (up to) $n^2$ substrings but (up to) $2^n$ subsequences.

Comment: @Raphael Interestingly, the OP gives examples that are good for substrings and subsequences, as far as I can see. Except for the fact that the third answer $aac$ is wrong in both cases since it occurs in string 5.  So the OP should make it clear whether he actually mean subsequence, i.e. composed of characters of a string in the right order, but not necessarily contiguous. I somehow doubt it, since the question says `a sub-sequence of a set of sequences` rather than `a sub-sequence of a set of strings` as it should if he made the proper distinction.

Comment: @babou thanks for pointing out the example error. I meant "contiguous substrings", and I didn't know about this distinction between string and sequence. Updated the question. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (the terminology of around subsequences is indeed not always and universally clear); this is indeed a duplicate then.

Comment: @Raphael the reduction from the many input strings (this question) to a single input string (the other question) is not too obvious to me (although it might be ovious to others :) ). We might want to reopen so that answers can clarify the reduction more explicitly and help future readers.

Comment: I know it works for just one string, but according to its description this should solve your problem if you concatenater all your strings into one long string.

Comment: @FrancescoGramano that reduction is not immediate to me, as it could create new substrings on the borders which could lead to a worse answer.

Comment: @CiroSantilli The other question only deals with only one string?

Comment: @Raphael I think yes: "Given a string S, ..."

Comment: Ahhh, we have multiple strings *here*, sorry. Well, my [second answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/39700/98) applies gracefully to multiple input strings. Suffix trees don't really care from how many strings the suffices come.

Comment: For your application, the answer is to not bother -- simply create a GUID and be done with it, that is going to be much faster than examining the input looking for a shorter string.  While it is going to be larger to send, that is going to be dwarfed in most cases by the savings going through the input just once.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution, similar to the linked question: [Algorithm Request: “Shortest non-existing substring over given alphabet”](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/algorithm-request-shortest-non-existing-substring-over-given-alphabet?lq=1)

Use a sliding window over each input string to build your `trie`.

- For `n=1` to `n=max(length(s))` where `s` is an input string, do:
- For each `s`, construct window of size `n`, slide window over `s` adding each window (substring of size `n`) to the `trie`, then
- Visit each `parent` of the `leaf set` of the `trie`. If there exists a `parent` node whose set of `child` nodes is smaller than the size of the `alphabet`, then you can form your desired string from this `parent` by appending a `character` from the `alphabet` that does not result in a string identical to one of the `leaf` nodes
- If no such `parent` node exists, continue to next larger `n`